# Solspace FreeForm Error on Submit

Tags: solspace

Does anyone know what this means? I get this when I submit my form ... ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Does this happen every time?  You may of waited too long before submitting it and the xid expired. Try turning off "Process form data in secure mode" under Security and Preferences and see if the issue persists. 
What version of FF and EE are you running?